# Slovenian characters in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

So i have a webview in which i want to display some html ... If i load html from web like this:

```
wv.loadUrl("http://www.somepage.com/somehtml.html");
```

It shows all characters like it should. Then i downloaded that code and save it to assets folder, now it laods but it doesn't show characters like š,ž,č correctly. I load it like that

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/samehtml.html");
```

In the head of html i have set charset to utf-8. Start of my html looks like thease...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1138.32">
</head>
```

Comment: Could you show how you saved that file? It's encoding is probably wrong. charset=utf-8 is just a hint for browser, not the actual encoding of file.

Comment: i went in eclipse select new file and type in name. then copy paste evrything into it...

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding. Change encoding to UTF-8, delete the file, create and save it again

Comment: Ok i solved it now, the problem was as u suggested in the actual encoding of the file. I created new file with utf8 encoding nad now it works. Thank u!